# The role of f(t) 1st Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

The first Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that d/dx (integral from a to x of f(t) dt) = f(x)

Why does f(t) not play a role in what d/dx (integral from a to x of f(t) dt) is? Apparently, only x does. For example, if you have d/dx (integral from a to x^2 of f(t) dt), then you have (x^2)'*f(t) through chain rule. In this case (and all other cases for that matter), whether or not f(t) is composite has no impact on the final answer. Why is that? For me, intuitively, if f(t) were composite, perhaps there would some impact if we need to use the chain rule (ie the example of x^2), but apparently not?

Comment: $t$ is just a dummy variable that fits inside the integral. (And I don't really know what you mean when you talk about $f(t)$'s complexity - $t$ is *just a letter*, the same as $x$...).

Comment: Complexity as in whether or not f(t) is a composite function or not. Sorry, I should have been more clear

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^{x^2} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{d(x^2)}{dx} f(x^2)$$

Comment: @ Hurkyl is there stuff in between those two? I know the equation above is true from the patterns I notice with example problems but I fail to see the detailed steps in between.

Comment: By composite function you mean it's the composition of two functions? By that standard what *wouldn't* be a composite function? (any function is the composition of itself with the function $x$). In any event, $f$ here refers to (pretty much) *any* function. The reason the derivative only depends on what's going on at the right endpoint of the integral and not on what happens between $a$ and $x$ is very interesting and perhaps surprising at first, and once you understand it you will understand the theorem. See the first picture here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: @Hurkyl.. Follow-up to proposer;s reponse to Hurkyl's comment: $\frac {d}{dx}\int_a^{x^2}f(t)dt=$ $=\frac {d(x^2)}{dx}\cdot \frac {d}{d(x^2)}\int_a^{(x^2)}f(t)dt=$ $\frac {d(x^2)}{dx}\cdot f(x^2)=2xf(x^2).$ ... To the proposer: Note that the theorem applies for $continuous$ $f$.

Comment: You should learn a bit of $\mathrm\LaTeX$ so that you can write math content clearly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common confusion. A definite integral (more precisely a Riemann integral) involves two things: a function and a closed interval on which the function is defined and bounded. Also it is obvious that the interval depends on its end-points. And thus in the symbol $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(t) \, dt$$ only $a, b, f$ matter. Then *why do we use $t$ in this notation?* The most convenient/familiar way to represent a function is by giving a formula for the image of some input under under this function. The letter $t$ is used to signify a generic point of domain of $f$ (which is interval $[a, b] $ here) and $f(t) $ is the image of $t$. Then why do we use $dt$? To signify that $t$ is the input for which $f(t) $ is the image.

Thus suppose we are given the integral as $\int_{1}^{4}(3t^{2}+1)$. In this notation we can't be sure if we are dealing with the function $f$ given by $f(t)=3t^{2}+1$ with $t$ as input or the function $g$ given by $g(t) =3t+1$ with $t^{2}$ as input. Another problem arises when the expression for $f$ involves more than one parameter like $\int_{1}^{2}(3a+bt)$. We don't know if the expression under integral sign represents image of input $t$ or $a$ or $b$.

So the dummy variable $t$ has its use especially when the function is given by a formula. Next we change the right hand end point of interval $[a, b] $ to $x$. This makes our interval of integration dependent on a variable $x$. And the value of integral depends on $f, a, x$ out of which $f, a$ are fixed and $x$ is variable. So this defines a function $F$ with domain $[a, b] $ and image of a point $x\in[a, b] $ under $F$ is given by the integral $$F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$$ The fundamental theorem of calculus says that the derivative of this function $F$ at point $c$ is equal to value of $f$ at $c$ ie $F'(c) =f(c) $ if $f$ is continuous at $c$. The notation in your question $$\frac{d} {dx}\int_{a}^{x} f(t) \, dt=f(x) $$ is just another way of saying $F'(x) =f(x) $. And clearly $t$ has no role to play here because the input variable of $F$ is chosen to be denoted by $x$. You can as well write $F'(t) = f(t) $ or $$\frac{d} {dt} \int_{a} ^{t} f(x) \, dx=f(t) $$

Answer (score 0):

When doing a definite integral (an integral with explicit upper and lower bounds), a variable disappears. That means that we need one more variable in the left side than we do in the right side. That is what $t$ does.

You can tell that it is intended to be a free variable because $dt$ tells you that the integration is with respect to $t$, so there is no room for composition stuff happening.